# How to filter duplicate records by column values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to get the values from table where only Isdefault records.[refer image for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Fet.png)

in the image TFN 831204456 has both Isdefault values 0 and 1, but i need to get values from IsDefault only 0 like TFN 965988826.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the rows which have duplicate values of TFN where IsDefault =0 only

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE TFN IN
   ( SELECT TFN
   FROM table1
   WHERE IsDefault =0
   GROUP BY TFN
   HAVING COUNT (*)  > 1) 
AND TFN NOT IN
    ( SELECT TFN
   FROM table1
   WHERE IsDefault =1
   GROUP BY TFN)
```

Comment: i need to get duplicate values only IsDefault = 0 for all TFN. if there are two records and one having IsDefault 1 then we need to omit that TFN.

Comment: Revised with the extra clause

Comment: sure will vote as answer once i got enough reputation credits.